# Is there a maximum size for QVector?

Tags: qt, qvector

I've tried to append 100 000 QString elements (each QString has about 10 characters in it) to a QVector. After that the program fails. Are there some limitations to how many elements a QVector can contain (besides physical memory limitations of course)? Besides, I think a have a lot free memory, enough to store such bunch of strings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Number of elements is limited to the limit of int, (about 2 billion). Your problem will be the size of what you're putting in it. Or some issue copying what you're putting in it.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of the code that fails? And by the way, [QList is usually recommended over the QVector](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/containers.html#the-container-classes).

Comment: show the code, avoid the speculation. Btw explain in more detail what type of failure you observe

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation.

> The QVector class is a template class that provides a dynamic array...
>   It stores its items in adjacent memory locations and provides fast
>   index-based access.

Knowing this the best way to append a large number of elements is to reserve to memory either using

```
QVector<QString> vector(100000);//or 
vector.reserve(100000);
```

This avoids relocating several times the memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try using QStringList as suggestet. I doubt a 100k strings would be a memory problem.

```
QStringList tlist;
for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) 
    tlist.append("1234567890");
```

runs totally fine within my environment

Answer (score 0):

From the [QVector documentation for Qt 5.14.2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html):

> The current version of QVector is limited to just under 2 GB (2^31 bytes) in size.